# access a list item c + +

Tags: c++

I store objects in a list. I want access their method but I do not see how to do it. In C#, I need to write:

```
for (i = 0; i < myList.count(); i++)
myList[i].update();
```

but C++ does not work :

```
list<Bullet> bullets;

bullets.emplace_back(t_bulletPlayer);

for (i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
{
   bullets[i].update();
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Show the actual C++ code that doesn't work.

Comment: It may not work because of any in an assortment of reasons you did not provide. What is the actual error? Are you using a custom list or a standard container? How did you insert the elements? How do you access the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::list`s in C++ do not have an indexed access operator. If you need indexed access often, you probably want a `std::vector` instead. For your use case of invoking a method on every object in your list, use a simple loop like this:

```
for (auto b : bullets)
  b.update();
```

Also, your use of `emplace_back` doesn't make sense (it should not even compile, but apparently MSVC++ has a nonconforming `emplace_back(T&&)`).  Use `push_back` to add an existing object of your type to a list or vector.